# Is there a way to permanently add a box displaying points of students in the navbar

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

So I am working on a project that awards points to students for submitting assignments or participating in forums, these points are then exposed as an Http resource using Flask.

The points are calculated by looking at the events triggered for each student.

One of the requirements right now is to add a box next to the student's name that shows the total amount of points they have. I have two ways of accessing the points, either by an http request from moodle or by storing and retrieving the points from moodle's database.

My question is what is the best approach of creating this "box", I have tried using moodle blocks and hacking the code but nothing seems to be working. Is creating a plugin for this the only solution or is there a simpler way to do it (if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question properly you should have provided at least the theme and the Moodle version you work with. Should this box be displayed everywhere? Is the score calculated for every course individually?

Two proposals that came into my mind:
You could create a custom plugin of type `block`. There you can display the score of the user of the session and the top ten for example (If the score is calculated for each course individually). A disadvantage is that every teacher of a course could remove that block easily, if he or she wants to.
If the score counts system-wide you could put that box at the start page of your Moodle website, where only people with higher rights will be able to remove it.

If you use boost you could display the score in the navbar right next to the users name. For that you will have to create a new child theme of boost and overwrite `navbar.mustache` of `theme_boost` which get's it's information from `columns2.php` because it's included into `columns2.mustache`. In this PHP file you can include your logic and display it with the HTML which you put into navbar.mustache.

Of course these are not really simple ways to do that. But at the moment I doubt that an easy solution exists for this problem.

Comment: A custom plugin of type block is indeed the way to go. It works by making an http post request to the application to retrieve the points.
An admin can set up the block to be visible in the dashboard page and this is exactly what we want.